Migrate SBS 2008 to 2019
My client has an old SBS 2008. It used to do their email until I migrated them to M365 a few months back. This server does not do any file-sharing or storage. It’s basically only the domain controller at this point.
I have a brand new Server 2019 STD. Right now, it’s just a basic server doing file storage and shares. It’s not doing any domain stuff (yet).
Since my SBS 2008 isn’t doing anything but being the DC - can I do a straight shot to migrate the DC functions to 2019? I was reading I need to jump to 2012 R2 then 2016, then to 2019. I’ve done migrations from 2008 to 2012 or 2019 in the past, but never an old SBS 2008 to 2019. Any suggestions or ideas? Things to watch out for or double-check?
Thank you in advance.

The process is basically the same:

Join your 2019 server to the domain
Promote your 2019 server to a domain controller
Make sure that DNS from anything with a static IP is switched to the new DC
Demote your 2008 server (this can be fun with SBS 2008 because there's a LOT of other crap jammed onto those servers. Truly a product of their time).
Turn off your SBS 2008 server
Raise your domain functional level to something from the last decade

Note that you really want your DC to be a dedicated standalone machine that doesn't do anything except DC stuff. If you are running virtualisation on your server, just make a second small VM for your DC. You are entitled to 4 virtual instances with your 2019 license.

I don't believe modern Windows  supports FRS, so SYSVOL will need to be converted to DFSR  before promotion.
